# How to find tel number in a tag with jquery regular expression

Tags: jquery, regex

Problem

I need to find all a tag which href value start with "tel:", I mean it should be a number. once this pattern found I need to put img left side of a tag

What I have done with regular express is here

```
  <a\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?href=(["'])(tel:.*?)\1
```

But I am not sure its a solution, I know its half solution but I dont know to execute it.

Expected output:
telephone number with img, so user can see it.

I need help here.

Comment: Do you need JS? I can provide you a only-CSS solution.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Yes, I need JS, I am working on chrome extension, it will read page and add img if number found

Comment: It's not relevant that you are working on chrome extension on this case, you can achieve with pure CSS too and give your extension better performance.

Comment: However I will put my CSS answer if it helps anothers.

Answer (score 2):

In both jQuery and CSS there is an `attribute` selector. This selector is `[` and `]`. The following selector will match any anchor with a `href` attribute beginning with "tel:":

```
$('a[href^="tel:"]');
```

The selector `^=` means "Begins with".

To put the same image before all telephone anchors:

```
$('a[href^=tel:]').before('<img src="/path/to/image"/>');
```

```js
jQuery(document).on('ready', function(){
  jQuery('a[href^="tel:"]').before('<img src="http://lorempixel.com/20/20/technics/"/>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Not a tel</a><br/>
<a href="tel:012345789">Tel</a>
```

Comment: I have seen this solution somewhere but not sure how to use it

Answer (score 2):

Here you are a solution with only CSS:

```
a[href^="tel:"] {
    padding-left: 30px;
    background: url(telephone.png) left center no-repeat;
}
```

Assuming the image has 24px of width, I give it 30px of padding to give some space between the icon and the telephone.

A working example:

```css
a[href^="tel:"] {
  padding-left: 150px;
  background: url('http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/token/128/Telephone-Alt.png') left center no-repeat;
  height: 128px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="tel:98176517892">98176517892</a>
```

Comment: I do like the css-only approach. Another is to use `:before` and set `content:url(/path/to/image);`.

Comment: Yes! You can do it with more techniques, but this is the basic technique easy to understand. However, I always prefer the `::before` pseudoselector.

Answer (score 1):

plain js solution:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[href^="tel:"]')
```

css solution:

```
a[href^="tel:"] {
    background-image: url(your_image_path)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> @Richard Parnaby-King 's answer looks better :)

Here you can do it with javascript. You may change the css for your needs. Right now what i only did was to differ tags with the ones that have a phone number and the others.

```js
  var aTag = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < aTag.length; i++) {
    var aTagContent =  aTag[i].href;
    var first = aTagContent.substr(0,   aTagContent.indexOf(':'));
    if (first == "tel") {
      $(aTag[i]).addClass( "myClass" );
    }
  }
```

```css
.myClass {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  padding:5px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  display: block;
]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="tel: +905554545566">+905554545566</a></body><br>
<a href="tel: +905554545567">+905554545567</a><br>
<a href="tel: +905554545568">+905554545568</a><br>
<a href="#">No telephone</a>
```